# Why only String[] args in java instead of Object[] args?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

In java, as per the [Java Language Specification 12.1.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4) the main method should be declared as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     //code of program
}
```

With the use of `String[] args` we can get command-line arguments. Sometime those command-line arguments needs to be converted to appropriate type. suppose if you have supplied any number `123` as an argument and you want to convert it to `int` then we can use one of the following conversion methods:

```
int n1=Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
//or
int n2=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

But, if java could have provided use of `Objects[] args` instead `String[] args` then we can easily convert from one type to another, for this example conversion would take place as follows:

```
public static void main(Object[] args){
     int n1=(Integer)args[0];
}
```

I'm not getting this why java have used `String[] args` and not `Object[] args`?

Comment: Simple. How can you pass a Object via your command line?

Comment: The command line provides strings. How would you distinguish between a string and an integer? Just being a numerical value is not enough to deem it an integer.

Comment: Ravi - It is good to think beyond the boundaries of what we do currently.  FYI - Powershell/.NET/C#/Cmdlets can actually do something like this  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714395%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  http://crazorsharp.blogspot.com/2009/12/powershell-like-command-line-arguments.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java is designed with portability in mind, so that Java programs would be invoked by diverse operating environments. Having the environments pass Java objects to `main` would put too much restrictions on the caller system, because that system would have a task of "understanding" the input and converting it to Java objects.

Strings, on the other hand, are universal: all operating environments have them. Therefore, Java specification required strings, knowing that your Java program would be able to process and understand them better than an external environment.

Answer (score 3):

This is simple because the `args` came from outside java environment, it is from the Operating System and as such it can't create Java Objects it can only pass Strings

To call a java program from a console it would be something like:

```
c:\java MyProgram 123
```

There is no way to java know that the OS is passing an object it is just a string.

Answer (score 2):

whenever you read from `Console` it is by default `String` that is the reason they have made it as `String[] array` .

if you use :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Enter String");
String str = br.readLine();
```

String variable `str` by contains String because `br.ReadLine()` gives you string

Answer (score 1):

Because you cannot pass an object via a command line argument.  Instead, it's natural to interpret the passed arguments as `Strings`.

Answer (score 1):

`public static void main(String[] args)` is a main method that runs when you execute the Class file `$java MyClass input1 input2`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the operating system doesn't pass variable typed arguments to the JVM. If you had `Object[] args` the JVM couldn't really infer their types like that without the Operating System. It's also the general contract (in Java of course) of "standard" (e.g. ancestral C/C++) [Main function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function_%28programming%29).

Answer (score 1):

May be because "String" is an array of char sequence which takes continuous memory, and which can be entered using standard keyboard. Otherwise how main method will  handle type casting.